# simple shopping feed xml generator - bedingte SHopping Preise in PHP

Tags: php, magento, feed

I'm trying to adjust the product feed in an older Magento 1 shop with the add-on "Simple Google Shopping" so that the shipping costs are returned depending on the product weight.

This Plugin is php-based: [User Guide](https://www.wyomind.com/google-shopping-magento.html?src=sgs-library&directlink=documentation#Simple_Google_Shopping_tutorial)

This is the snippet of code that doesn't work for me. Do you have any idea what the problem could be?

```
<g:price>
<?
if( {weight} >= 31.5) 
{return 79.90;} 
else 
{return 4.00;}
?>
</g:price>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution:

The problem was that, contrary to the user guide, the variable call has to look like this:

**$weight** and not '{weight}' or '$product->weight'